# How to change the form action in C# .NET through code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project in C# .NET that allows me only one form in the .aspx file.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="#1">
```

How can I change the form action through the C# code in a method? 
I have tried this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.Action = "#2";
}
```

but it didn't work. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What to you want to achive be changing actions? Perhaps [CrossPage  posting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) is what you actually need.

Comment: This isn't how it is supposed to work.  With asp.net, the system expects to post back to the original page in order to restore ViewState on Controls on the page.  If you post back to another page, the ViewState will not make sense to that "other" page.

Comment: You can issue a Response.Redirect in the OnClick handler of that button.

Comment: I have two different forms in the same page and with #1 i am showing the first form and with #2 the second one. When I post something in the second form and it has an error I 'd like to go back at the same form with the previous values. With Response.Redirect, my alert message cannot be displayed.

Comment: Use one form with two `asp:panel` controls.  Put the form elements in each of those panels as you have them seperated by form at the moment. Hide and show the panels as required on postback between the two.

Answer (score 0):

(Moving this to the top because it's an answer to the newly understood question. It's not how to change the form action, but how to have multiple forms.)

If you want a server form on a page that already has a server form then perhaps that second "form" should be a [User Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx). That way it sits inside the host page's server form but doesn't require its own form. And it's self-contained, able to contain whatever logic it needs when handling a postback.

Here's an example of a simple User Control. You can create one from Add > New Item > Web > Web Forms User Control.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="OtherForm.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.OtherForm" %>
<label for="<% = OtherFormTextInput.ClientID %>">
    This is some other form on the same page
</label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="OtherFormTextInput"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" Text="Submit this other form"/>
```

It looks like an .aspx page but it has no form. It can still have its own code behind which can interact with with the other server controls it contains, just like an .aspx page would.

Then you add that control to your "main" page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!-- Register the user control -->
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="other" Src="~/OtherForm.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- This form has its own stuff, but also contains the "other" form. -->
        <uc:other runat="server" ID="TheOtherForm"></uc:other>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I recommend this over using panels (which still works) because if you're putting two forms on one page, it's likely that you might at some point want to move the secondary form to another page or re-use it. This approach keeps it completely self-contained. Its code-behind isn't in the same file as the the .aspx page. You can place this on as many pages as you want.

---

Original "literal" answer which addresses the question as originally understood.

The `runat="server"` form exists entirely for the purpose of allowing ASP.NET to interact with the page and its server controls during postbacks. It's central to the way webforms works. If you change the action then technically what you have isn't a webforms page any more.

That's fine (I don't even like webforms) but it can lead to some weird behavior. If you have controls that trigger postbacks then normally they'd be handled on the same page and your user would just see a (hopefully) fast refresh. Now they might get sent to another page.

What if you just removed that form entirely and added your own form instead? Then your .aspx page will just behave more like an .html page.

Having added all the disclaimers about why not to do it, you can change the action using JavaScript. Here's a sample:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:Button runat="server" text="Causes postback"/>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"/>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("form1").action = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some browsers might not allow changing the form's action.

I put the checkbox there just for fun (I must be really bored) to show the odd side effects it could have, that you might click on a checkbox and get redirected to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to you question. [asp:Panel](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_panel_controls.htm) Controls could help you out.

A very rough example

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel id="Form1" runat="server">
        <!-- Form 1 Stuff -- >
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
           OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </panel>
     <asp:Panel id="Form2" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <!-- Form 2 Stuff -- >
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
           OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    </panel>
</form>
```

C#

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //HIde "Form"1
    Form1.Visible = false;
    //Show "Form"2
    Form2.Visible = true;
    //Do other stuff
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Final Processig
}
```

Also look at the [DefaultButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Panel

Answer (score 0):

You can write a response.write() in your Asp.net side that print some javascript or jQuery code! As @Scott Hannen wrote some javascript like this :

```
Response.Write("<script>document.getElementById('YOURFORMID').action = 'YOUR URL';</script>");
```

or with jQuery

```
Response.Write("<script>$('#YOUR FORM ID').attr('action', 'YOUR URL');</script>");
```

btw if you have access to .html or .js files u can directly put this jQuery code without any C# code!